# What Software Patterns does the Bitcoin source code use?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, architecture

I'm a Master Student in Computing Science and currently investigating the [Bitcoin source code](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin) on the Software Patterns that are used. Part of the assignment is to ask the community to guide us.

I would like to ask you if you know any Software Pattern in the source code. In order to give you a view of our scope, below is a list of Patterns covered (Design Patterns and Architectural Patterns).

Thanks in advance,

Patrick

Object Oriented Design Patterns:

- Factory Pattern
- Adapter Pattern
- Composite Pattern
- Facade Pattern
- Proxy Pattern
- Observer Pattern

Architectural Patterns:

- Layered Decomposition Pattern
- Pipes And Filters Pattern
- Data Repository Pattern
- Model View Controller Pattern
- Client Server Pattern
- Peer to Peer Pattern
- Publish Subscribe Pattern
- Broker Pattern
- Message Queue Pattern

Answer (score 2):

i don't think you can find many Object Oriented Design Patterns in the btc-source-code. but there is one example i know:

the blockchain itself is like a composite pattern:
you have a general type called `Block`. two types inherits `Block`: `MinedBlock` inherits from `Block` and `GenesisBlock` inherits from `Block`. A `MinedBlock` has one attribute of the type `Block` called `PreviousBlock`. 
(here you can also find the *singleton* pattern: you need exactly one `GenesisBlock`-object.)